# How to modify column value? (JPA)

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I need to change the value of a column using JPA query syntax(JPQL), how can i do it?

This is how i retrieve the row that i want to update:

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Role activateUser(long id) {
        Query query = em
                .createQuery("SELECT r.id FROM Role r WHERE r.id=" + id);
        Role tmpRole = (Role) query.getSingleResult();
        tmpRole.setAccountStatus(AccountStattus.ACTIVATED.toString());
        //How can i create query to save the changes here?)
        return tmpRole;
    }
```

Is there any other alternative to modify that row without retrieving it first?

What do you think is the best approach from the point of view of performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JPA in JPA way:

1) Load the entity, then it is attached to the current transaction. 
2) Change the entity
3) Commit the transaction

The transaction handling can be done for example be @Transactional, but Java EE 5/6 has many other ways to do that.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

//@Transactional - Not Java EE, anyway I keep it as notice that the method is invoked in a transaction.
public Role activateUser(long id) {
    Role role = em.find(Role.class, id);        
    role.setAccountStatus(AccountStattus.ACTIVATED.toString());
    //Thats all.
}
```

Comment: That code is inside an EJB, do i need the transactional annotation?

Comment: No, EJB's open an transaction per default. (I know it for JEE6 and guess it is the same for JEE5 to)

Comment: I supposed that. I am trying your code but i don't manage to modify the value, maybe it has to do with something else in my code, i will check. (1+)

Comment: @sfrj: Check that your transaction is not read only. -- This is my personal typical error.

Comment: How can i check that? I dont really understand(I dont use transactional annotation)

Comment: @sfrj: as long as you did not write something like `@Transactional(REQUIRED, readOnly=true)` the the transaction is read write.

Comment: There are two things that are not good in your code. First there should be return em.merge(role); at the end of method. Otherwise database won't be updated. Second thing is about your annotation. @Transactional isn't JEE6 annotation. You should either skip it (in EJB there will be implicit transaction) or use @TransactionAttribute with proper transaction type.

Comment: @jgrabowski: I agree with @Transactional. But are you sure that I need to call merge to persist an entity LOADED by em.find? When I understand the Life Cycle correct, then merge is to put a detached entity in a managed entity. If merge is invoked on a already manged entity then merge do noting (useful) "If A is an existing managed entity, it is ignored. However, the merge operation still cascades.as defined below."

Comment: @Ralph you're right. If it's managed merge will do nothing more. Upvoted your answer again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A

```
em.flush
```

after

```
tmpRole.setAccountStatus(AccountStattus.ACTIVATED.toString());
```

should be enough. As i recall, as long as a bean is managed by the EntityManager (which is the case here), all changes are automatically reflected.

If this doesn't work, then maybe try

```
tmpRole.setAccountStatus(AccountStattus.ACTIVATED.toString());
em.merge(tmpRole);
```

edit:
BTW, for finding the role you can also write

```
em.find(Role.class, id);
```

if you have mapped the ID in the Role class correctly.